# How to define a function that works on unrelated types in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

I'd like to define a function that applies `* 2` to its argument, that works for all types where it's meaningful. I tried using structural types:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
def double[T](x: Any{def * (arg0: Int): T}) = x * 2
```

It works for strings:

```
scala> double("a")
res85: String = aa
```

But not for numbers:

```
scala> double(4)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.$times(int)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1778)
  at .reflMethod$Method1(<console>:18)
  at .double(<console>:18)
  ... 32 elided
```

1. Why do I get this error message?
2. Is it possible to do what I want using structural types?
3. Is it possible to do it in some other way?

**Edit**: By "do what I want" I mean working for already existing types, such as numbers and strings, not just for classes that I define myself.

Comment: @wheaties It wasn't me who downvoted your answer.

Comment: @michau type classes are applicable to any existing type, as you want.

Comment: Apologies then. Guess I've been on this site too long to not make inferences.

Comment: @dveim How can I do it with type classes, then?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: You poked into a really interesting bug here. We could separate this into two unrelated questions; one would be what you asked under numbers 2 and 3 (and yes, answer to that is "type classes") and another would be why is compiler acting this way. E.g. why it doesn't work for `Int` the way you describe it, but after switching `{def * (arg0: Int): T}` into `{def * (arg0: Int): Int}` it works.

Comment: Well, structural types can't have type parameters. That's one of the limitations to structural types. So it will work when you make all the types concrete. You just can't make them abstract like that.

Comment: @wheaties As far as I know the limitation is that they can't have type parameters in the argument list, and this is detected by the compiler. Type parameters in return values should be fine.

Comment: Compiler bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3669

Answer (score 3):

1. `*` is translated to `$times`, structural type checks existence of `*` method, but (I suppose that's a bug) calls it's internal (`$times`) representations). That works for `String`, because there *is* `$times` for them.
2. This approach should work for methods with names that only contain letters.

```

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
def double[T](x: Any{def test (arg0: Int): T}) = x.test(2)

class A { def test(i: Int) = i * 10 }
class B { def test(i: Int) = i * 20 }

scala> double(new A)
res0: Int = 20

scala> double(new B)
res1: Int = 40
```

3. Yes, idiomatic answer is *typeclasses*. You choose what exactly "meaningfulness" is. And they can be applied to any already existing class:

```

```
trait Multiply[A]{
  def times(a: A, x: Int): A
}

implicit val MultString = new Multiply[String] { def times(a: String, x: Int) = a * x }
implicit val MultInt = new Multiply[Int] { def times(a: Int, x: Int) = a * x }

def double[T](t: T)(implicit mult: Multiply[T]) = mult.times(t, 2)

scala> double("aaaa")
res0: String = aaaaaaaa

scala> double(111)
res1: Int = 222
```

Also note that structural typing uses reflection => is quite slow.

Comment: It's not really that simple. For example, defining double() as  `double[T](x: Any {def * (arg0: Int): T})` doesn't work when invoked with `double[Int](3)`, but when defined as `double(x: Any {def * (arg0: Int): Int})` it works when invoked with `double(3)`. Why?

Comment: I think both should work, and there's a bug in implementation. Probably when you provide full types compiler is not mind-blown.

Comment: My question is: how to make `double` work correctly with already existing types (e.g. strings and numbers)? Your answer doesn't tell me what I should do to make both `double("a")` and `double(2)` produce expected results.

Comment: @michau See example.

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `new` over `implicit object MultString extends Mutiply[String]`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz vals are not lazy initialized, they have less bytecode and size and they can be overridden in subclass. Personally I prefer vals.

Answer (score 3):

You could always just overload the method.  To make it work in the REPL you have to `:paste` it in as a block.

```
def double(s:String):String = s * 2
def double[N](n:N)(implicit ev: Numeric[N]):N = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  n * ev.fromInt(2)
}

double("this")  // result: String = thisthis
double(3L)      // result: Long = 6
```

Comment: That's not the same as applying `* 2`. Of course `x * 2` equals `x + x` for numbers and strings, but I can't be sure it's the case for any type.

Comment: But I  can see that it's possible to do it in a similar way: `def double(s:String):String = s*2` and `def double[N](x:N)(implicit n: Numeric[N]):N = n.times(x,n.fromInt(2))`

Comment: One more possibility, which makes the function body more readable: `import Numeric.Implicits._; def double[N <% Numeric[N]#Ops](n: N)(implicit f: Int => N) = n * 2`

Comment: @michau `<%` is deprecated and will be removed someday.

Comment: OK, one more try: `import Numeric.Implicits._; type NumOps[T] = T => Numeric[T]#Ops; def double[T: NumOps](n: T)(implicit f: Int => T) = n * 2`

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility I've found is to use macros. As of Scala 2.11.8 they are still experimental and, [according to Martin Odersky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHzWqJKFCk4), won't survive in this form. The current synax is clumsy, but so far it is the only method that is completely DRY (`* 2` is written only once, and the function works on all types that support this operation).

Regardless of whether this is the best solution, I'm posting it for the sake of completeness:

```
import reflect.macros.Context
def doubleImpl[T](c: Context)(x: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[T] = {
  import c.universe._
  c.Expr(q"${x.tree} * 2")
}
def double[T](x: T): T = macro doubleImpl[T]
```